# Complicated SQL query data binding to DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have gone to this complicated SQL query while trying to make application for existing database, and it transfers to DataGrid.

```
private void buttonlaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataAkt.DataContext = GetComments("SELECT a1.*, inspectors.cFullName, organizations.cOrgName, d1.cString, d2.cString, d3.cString, towns.cTownName " +
                                            "FROM akt as a1 "+
                                            "left join inspectors on  a1.nDocInspektor = inspectors.ROWID "+
                                            "left join organizations on organizations.nDirectoryType = organizations.ROWID "+
                                            "left join directories as d1 on a1.nOrgFormVlast = d1.ROWID "+
                                            "left join directories as d2 on a1.nOrgVidPidpr = d2.ROWID "+
                                            "left join directories as d3 on a1.nOrgVidEPDial = d3.ROWID "+
                                            "left join towns on a1.nDocMisceSkladannya=towns.ROWID").DefaultView;
    }
```

in XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataAkt" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="dataAkt_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,10,0,0">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cName}" Header="Название/комментарий" Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ROWID}" Header="Номер"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cDocNomer}" Header="Номер документа"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=dDocDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" Header="Дата составления"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgName}" Header="Субъект хозяйствования"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cFullName}" Header="Персонал ГОСТРУД"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cDocUch1}" Header="При участии"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=organizations.cOrgName}" Header="Тип организации"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d1.cString}" Header="Форма собственности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d2.cString}" Header="Вид предпринимательства"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d3.cString}" Header="Вид экономической деятельности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=towns.cTownName}" Header="Место составления"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgAdresa}" Header="Адрес организации"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgPhoneFax}" Header="Телефон/Факс"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cPosPIB}" Header="Фамилия, имя, отчество"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cPosPosada}" Header="Должность"  Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=fPerZaborg}" Header="Задолженность, тыс. руб"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=fPerZaborgZv}" Header="Зад. уволенным, тыс. руб"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MyBoolValue, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}}" Header="Проверка в ночное время"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=nPerPropoz}" Header="Внесено предложений"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgIndKod}" Header="Идентификационный номер"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgFormVlastKod}" Header="Код формы собственности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=cOrgVidEPDialKod}" Header="Код вида экономической деятельности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

MySQL Workbench gives me resulting table with all columns that I need, BUT in `dataAkt` colunms `organizations.cOrgName` `d1.cString` `d2.cString` `d3.cString` coluns are emply. Can't solve why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give meaningful aliases to your columns. You have:

```
organizations.cOrgName AS ocOrgName, d1.cString, d2.cString, d3.cString ...
```

Change this to:

```
organizations.cOrgName AS ocOrgName, d1.cString AS d1cString, d2.cString AS d2cString, d3.cString AS d3cString ...
```

Now you can bind correctly to the columns like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ocOrgName}" Header="Тип организации"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d1cString}" Header="Форма собственности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d2cString}" Header="Вид предпринимательства"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=d3cString}" Header="Вид экономической деятельности"  Width="100"  IsReadOnly="True" />
```

The problem is that a column selected as `towns.cTownName` will not get the name `towns.cTownName` in the result set, it will be named `cTownName`, without the table prefix. Since the tables, `d1`, `d2` and `d3` all have columns with the same name (`cString`) you need to give them aliases to be able to distinct which is which.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new into this and knew nothing about aliases in SQL, this query is most complicated query that I did ever. Worked nice and smooth